# How to improve my update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and I have 2 tables, the first called MCross

It has 3 columns

```
Brand1  Brand2  Cnt
--------------------
Mazda   Toyota  NULL
Ford    Toyota  NULL
Nissan  Mazda   NULL
BMW     Opel    NULL
Nissan  BMW     NULL
```

and the other table called Tags

```
AgentID  Brand     Class
----------------------
1        Toyota    C
1        Toyota    S
1        BMW       X7
1        BMW       X5 
1        BMW       X3
1        Mazda     3
2        Toyota    C
2        Toyota    S
2        Mazda     5
2        Mazda     3
3        BMW       X3
3        Nissan    P
4        Nissan    L
4        BMW       X3
```

I want to update MCross with number of agents that has both Brand1 and Brand2

I tried this

but it is very very slow and i think this can be written in a better way

```
update A
    set Cnt = B.cnt
from MCross A
inner join (
    select C.Brand1, C.Brand2, count(T.AgentID) cnt
    from MCross C
    inner join (
        select AgentID, ','+STRING_AGG(cast(Brand as NVARCHAR(MAX)),',')+',' AS Brands
        from Tags
        group by AgentID
    ) T on T.Brands Like  '%,'+C.Brand1+',%' and T.Brands Like  '%,'+C.Brand2+',%' 
    group by C.Brand1, C.Brand2
) B on A.Brand1 = B.Brand1 and A.Brand2 = B.Brand2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can use `apply`:

```
update m
   set m.cnt = a.num_agents
   from mcross m outer apply
        (select count(*) as num_agents
         from (select t.agentid
               from tags t
               where t.brand in (m.brand1, m.brand2)
               group by t.agentid
               having count(distinct t.brand) = 2
              ) a
        ) a;
```

Note:  If you want this for *all* brand pairs in the data, simply use a self-join:

```
with a as (
      select distinct agentid, brand
      from tags
     )
select a1.brand, a2.brand, count(*)
from a a1 join
     a a2
     on a1.agentid = a2.agentid and
        a1.brand <> a2.brand
group by a1.brand, a2.brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

**Edit:**

```
UPDATE m
SET m.Cnt = (
    SELECT COUNT(AgentId)
    FROM (
        SELECT AgentId, ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT Brand), 0) Total
        FROM Tags WHERE Brand = m.Brand1 OR Brand = m.Brand2
        GROUP BY AgentId
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Brand) = 2) T
    )
FROM MCross m
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that same brand can be repeated for the same agency

Comment: Check the new one.